# Percolate query alternative for given use case

Tags: elasticsearch

I asked this over in Elastic's forums but am not getting any response so I am checking here.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/percolate-query-alternative-for-given-use-case/207165

---

I'm checking to see if there is a better way to achieve the same goal that the percolate query does for me but with less overhead.

I have an index where each document is a product (say Acme Anvils). I want to determine if a piece of text, say a customer review, is mentioning a specific product. The way I have this currently working is that each document that represents a product has a field of type `percolator` and the value for that is a `match_phrase` query. Here is the index template and example document

**Index Template**

```
PUT /_template/product-percolate-test
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "product-percolate-test"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "refresh_interval": "1s",
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
    "english_stop": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": "_english_"
    },
    "english_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "english"
    },
    "english_possessive_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "possessive_english"
    }
      },
      "analyzer": {
    "english_search": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "english_possessive_stemmer",
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "english_stop",
        "english_stemmer"
      ]
    },
    "english_mention": {
      "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "english_stop"
      ]
    }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "abv": {
    "type": "double"
      },
      "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "analyzed": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english_search"
      }
    }
      },
      "manufacturer": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "analyzed": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english_search"
      }
    }
      },
      "percolator-message": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "english_mention"
      },
      "percolator-query": {
    "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Product Document**

```
{
  "_index" : "product-percolate-test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "00c68132-19b5-488f-8ea9-ee4b5d97a996",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Anvil 3000 Deluxe",
    "manufacturer" : "Acme",
    "percolator-query" : {
      "match_phrase" : {
    "percolator-message" : {
      "query" : "Anvil 3000 Deluxe",
      "slop" : 1
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this, I can run the following percolate query and get the following results:

**Percolate Query**

```
GET /product-percolate-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "percolator-query",
      "document": {
    "percolator-message" : "I purchased the Anvil 3000 Deluxe from Acme about a week ago. I would not recommend this product. Although it is a good anvil, I have yet been able to successfully catch any road runners with it. It instead keeps falling on my head."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Percolate Results**

```
{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6538229,
    "hits" : [
      {
    "_index" : "product-percolate-test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "00c68132-19b5-488f-8ea9-ee4b5d97a996",
    "_score" : 0.6538229,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "Anvil 3000 Deluxe",
      "manufacturer" : "Acme",
      "percolator-query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
          "percolator-message" : {
            "query" : "Anvil 3000 Deluxe",
            "slop" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "fields" : {
      "_percolator_document_slot" : [
        0
      ]
    }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are the issues I see with this:

- There is a percolate query for each product document and the number of documents is likely to reach into the tens-of-thousands
- The percolate query for each product document is exactly the same with the exception of the `match_phrase` query value which is always the product name
- If i need to change the queries used for this, i would need to modify each document likely through a `reindex` operation

I am wondering if there is a more optimal way of achieving the same result.

Thank you

Comment: Why you can't use the match_phrase query on the percolator_message field directly, without creating the percolator field? Which is the reason to use the percolator?

Comment: @Lupanoide i'm not sure i fully understand your question but i'll answer best i can. the percolate query requires use of an empty field on the product document so that it can use that fields mappings when creating the in-memory document containing the actual message text to execute each percolate query against. because i need to find all possible products that are mentioned in the text, not just one, and because the message text is not actually stored, i cannot run a match_phrase on the message text itself.

Comment: can you index the product name as documents WITHOUT percolator query, and use a `match` query of your review text, and sort by scores? the top scored doc is most likely mentioned in the input review.

Comment: @fasttooth i don't believe a match_phrase wouldn't work comparing the text to the product names based on how match_phrase works. I originally was comparing the text to the product names with a match, but the results were not great due to various reasons. Percolate seems to be designed for my use case, but because all my percolate queries for each product are the same, i was hoping for a more short hand  means (a.k.a. a single query) for doing the same. I was looking for how to execute queries that compares docs from one index to another but not finding much there either.

Comment: hmm, iam out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @fasttooth no worries. thank you though.